# fetch array in javascript from cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, rgraph

[here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwG0n.png)    
//need to import values of data from .cs file

```
    data = [12,36,40]


    new RGraph.Bar({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: data,
        options: {
            textAccessible: true,
            scaleZerostart: true,
            backgroundGridAutofitNumvlines: 0,
            linewidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            hmargin: 7,
            colors: ['Gradient(pink:red:#f33)', 'Gradient(green:#0f0)'],
            labelsAbove: true,
```

//need to import values of lables from .cs file

```
            labels: ["mon","tue","wed"],
            clearto: 'white',
            variant: '3d',
            gutterBottom: 90,
            noaxes: true
        }
    }).wave({ frames: 60 });
</script>
```

I need to fetch the values of data and values of labels from .cs file in R graph.

Comment: Are these value-files stored on a server? If so, look at AJAX to go and get them.

Comment: I have alredy tried using Ajax Barchart.But some of the values are not being displayed. i have attached the same above.